# Cambiar idioma en ios app

Tags: ios, swift2

Estoy haciendo una app en español con swift2, pero hay cosas que salen en inglés como por ejemplo cuando uso la camara desde la app pone "Take photo".

Como puedo cambiar el idioma a español?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A mi también me paso, pero lo he solucionado cambiando el titulo programaticamente, Te indico un ejemplo:

```
self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem.title = "Aceptar"
```

Para cambiar el idioma cuando sale el menu contextual de la camara, lo puedes cambiar de la siguinet form:

1- Creas un archivo llamado: `Localizable.strings`

2- Añades la frase original y la traducción

Ejemplo:

```
"Choose From Library" = "Coger de la libreria";
"Take Photo" = "Sacar foto";
"Cancel" = "Cancelar";
```

La informavión la he sacado de [aqui](http://www.migueldiazrubio.com/desarrollo-ios-internacionalizar-tu-aplicacion/)

Comment: Eso es para la navigation bar :S necesito para search bar y camara

Comment: Se aplica lo mismo para el search bar y para lo de la camara, cambia el idioma del simulador desde sus ajustes

Comment: Vale he solucionado lo de la barra, lo de la cámara aun no. Lo de cambiar el idioma del simulador, no hace falta, porque la app la estoy probando en un iphone real y tiene todo en español

Comment: @AlbertoMier creo que para la cámara es un poco distinto (y no tengo claro que se pueda, porque creo que engancha directamente el idioma del sistema). Pero buena respuesta :)